# Trigger a function to close a modal window in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm creation my portfolio section in ReactJS with Gatsby and I have some trouble to handle KeyDown.
My code permits me to detect when I'm pressing on ESC key but I can't trigger the close function as I did for the overlay (onClick event).
I have three differents files :

- `modal.js` - Modal component
- `project.js` - Project component
- `projets.js` - project page

I create the modal window which will display the details of the project. The project component will display all the project thumbnails and finally the project page will render the Project Component.

Maybe there's something that I missing. I will appreciate your help.

Here is the code for the modal component :
**modal.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Link } from 'gatsby-link'
import './modal.scss'
import MdClose from 'react-icons/lib/md/close'
export class Modal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.initializeEscClosing();
    }

    initializeEscClosing() {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
                if (e.which == 27) {
                    //this.props.onClose
                    console.log('It\'s working')
                }
            });
        }
    }


    render() {


        // Render nothing if the "show" prop is false

        if (!this.props.show) {
            return null;
        }

        return (
            <div className={`modal`}>
                <div className={`modal__overlay`}
                    onClick={this.props.onClose}
                    onKeyDown = {
                      this.initializeEscClosing
                    }
                    tabIndex = "0"


                >
                </div>
                <div className={`modal__container`}>

                    <div className={`modal__body`}>
                        <div className={`top`}>
                            <button onClick={this.props.onClose}><MdClose /></button>
                        </div>
                        <div className={`content`}>
                            {this.props.children}
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        )
    }
}
Modal.propTypes = {
    onClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    show: PropTypes.bool,
    children: PropTypes.node
};

export default Modal
```

I noticed that when I'm pressing on `ESC`, the function is triggered 3 times because I have 3 projects in my `.json` file.  How can I fix this issue ?

Here is the code for the project component :

project.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import {Link} from 'gatsby-link'
import './project.scss'
import {LinkWebsite, ButtonProject} from '../../../components/atoms/button'


import {Modal } from '../modal'


export class Project extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            opened:false
        }
     this._toggleModal = this._toggleModal.bind(this)

    }
    _toggleModal(){   
      this.setState({
          opened: !this.state.opened
      })
    }

    render(){
        const { title, category, image, logo, children, website} = this.props

        return(
           <div className="project__container">
                <div className="project__preview">
                    <button onClick={this._toggleModal}>
                    {logo ? <img src={logo.src} alt={title} /> : null}
                    <h2>{title} <span className="category">{category}</span></h2>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className="project__details">
                    <Modal 
                        onClose={this._toggleModal}
                        show={this.state.opened}
                    >

                                {image ? <img src={image.src} alt={title} /> : null}
                                <h3>{title} <span className="category">{category}</span></h3>


                                {children}


                                {website ? <LinkWebsite link={website}>Voir le site</LinkWebsite> : null}


                    </Modal>
                </div>
                </div>



        )
    }

}
export default Project

Project.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    category: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    image: PropTypes.shape({
        src: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        alt: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }).isRequired,
    logo: PropTypes.shape({
        src: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        alt: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }).isRequired,
    children: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
    website: PropTypes.string,
};

Project.defaultProps = {
    title: 'Nom du projet',
    image: null,
    logo: null,
    children: 'Texte introductif du projet. Il fourni les éléments clés',
    website: null,
};
```

Here is the code for the project page :

projets.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Link from 'gatsby-link'
import { Project } from '../components/molecules/project'

const projectPage = ({ data }) => {

    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Projets r&eacute;cents</h1>
      <div className="projects__container">

            {data.allProjectsJson.edges.map(({ node }, i) =>
                       (<Project
                           key={i}
                           title={node.title}
                           category={node.category}
                           image={{
                               src: node.image.childImageSharp.original.src,
                               alt: node.title,
                           }}
                          logo={{
                            src: node.logo.childImageSharp.original.src,
                            alt: node.title,
                          }}
                           website={node.website}
                       >
                           <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: node.description }} />
                       </Project>),
                   )}

            </div>
            </div>
        )



}

export default projectPage

export const pageQuery = graphql`
query ProjectsQuery {
  allProjectsJson {
    edges {
      node {
        title
        category
        description
        image {
          childImageSharp {
            original {
              src
            }
          }
        }
        logo {
          childImageSharp {
            original {
              src
            }
          }
        }
        website
      }
    }
  }
}
`;
```

Thank you in advance for taking the time to help
Wish you a great Friday,

Kind regards,
Maral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there is something not completely correct in the  initializeEscClosing() function.
Why you create a listener inside it ? onKeyDown is a listener itselfs.
Try to do something like this to trigger the event.

```
<div onKeyDown = {event =>  this.keyDownHandler(event)}/>
```

event prop has all the infos about the key event so in the function that handles it you could check if the key is the correct one and eventually close the modal

Comment: Andrea, thanks for answering. There is something that I don't understand. when I'm pressing on ESC it trigger the function. The modal disapear but the two other doesn't. In the console the function is triggered as many I have projects

Comment: I added a condition, so my bug is fixed, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using arrow functions, I don’t have a laptop handy, apologize for that, but you can try something like this

```
// Modal component 
...
onClick={()=> {this.props.onClose()}

// Project component
onClose={() => {console.log(‘might be triggered’); this.toggleModal()}}
```

Using arrow functions gets rid you of binding the functions from constructors

[source](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html)

Comment: Lucaci, thanks for the answer but I have no problems when I click on the overlay, when I want to do is to trigger toggleModal in the modal component when I press ESC

Comment: Oh, apologize for not understanding correctly. Try using arrow function for that function. Something like ‘onKeyDwon={()=>this.initializeEscClosing()}’. Or bind this function in constructor as you did for toggling in Project component.